# No robot hardware, How to study ROS?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not robot hardware, how to study ROS?  how to debug appliction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38711/no-robot-hardware,-how-to-study-ros?/) by [hjh2008](https://answers.ros.org/users/2832/hjh2008/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are various robot simulators, based on [stage](http://ros.org/wiki/stage) or [gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo).

EDIT: Most of the [officially listed robots](http://ros.org/wiki/Robots) have some kind of simulation procedure. The quality and detail no doubt vary depending on the needs of those projects.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-12**:
if you wanna use a UAV i can advise you the hector_quadrotor stack, works pretty fine with gazebo an rviz

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-07-13**:
You should also consider using Morse (http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse/).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-16**:
Just saw this very cool announcement: http://www.iheartrobotics.com/2012/07/get-your-own-simulated-robonaut.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+IHeartRobotics+%28I+Heart+Robotics%29&utm_content=Google+Reader

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, you should complete the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials). They are excellent and don't require any hardware. My experience is that people who do the tutorials first save a lot of time later.

As a next step, I agree that a simulator is the best way to go. Personally, I'd recommend the [turtlebot Gazebo simulation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator) over the PR2 one, since the Turtlebot things tend to be simpler and easier to grasp.

As a third step, there are several cheap pieces of hardware that work with ROS and that you might already have access to:

1. Do you have an Android phone? You can visualize your phone's accelerometer/magnetometer/gyroscope data in RViz using [android_sensors_driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/android_sensors_driver), or you can teleop your (simulated) robot around using [android teleop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ros.android.teleop&hl=de). Both projects don't quite work out of the box (you'll need some additional parts except from the two I linked to), so you'll have a little project to learn ROS on. Don't hesitate to open up another question if you need help.
2. Do you have a Microsoft Kinect? You can do some of the [Point Cloud Library (PCL) tutorials](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/), and then think up an own little project. The PCL is now a separate project from ROS, but basically all the point cloud perception in ROS is done using the PCL.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5